# Run rake task on Heroku with arguments and the Heroku app specified

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake

I have a rake task that I used to run with arguments like this:

```
heroku rake query:process -a myherokuapp
```

Now that rake task accepts arguments. If I were running it locally, I can call them like this:

```
rake query:process -- -d true -c false
```

When I try to run this process on Heroku, it doesn't like the combination of the arguments and the app.

```
# These don't work
heroku rake query:process -- -d true -c false -a myherokuapp
heroku -a myherokuapp rake query:process -- -d true -c false
```

Is it possible to run this rake task with arguments on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

`heroku -a myherokuapp run rake:process -- -d true -c false`